# Get string of url from javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i am using this code to get this path : **http://192.168.1.5:83/staging/eleave/application/view/leave_approval.php**

```
var url = document.location.toString();
```

Question is how to get this path only? : **http://192.168.1.5:83/staging/eleave/application/**

Comment: Why upto `/application`? Why not upto `/view`, or `/eleave` You need to phrase the question better.

Comment: I misread your question. I thought you wanted the path of the URL

Comment: what? that isn't anything. it's not the base url, it's not the full path, its not the path minus the file... it's just some random chunk of a URL. how is the function supposed to determine where it should end? 3 levels deep, or what?

Comment: Also, what are you doing? Normally you wouldn't create an absolute link in JavaScript to the current site - `../../` can work well for most uses.

Comment: i want the path so i can use it in ajax call in the url. before this that chunk is using php define variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many folders you need in the url then:

```
var splittedUrl = url.split("/");
var depth = 5;
var neededUrl = '';
for (i = 0; i < depth; i++)
{
   neededUrl += splittedUrl[i] + '/';
}
```